# grid.arrange from gridExtras exiting with “only 'grobs' allowed in 'gList'” after update

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I used package 'VennDiagram' to draw four venn diagram called P1,P2,P3,P4. Then want to grid.arrange to put four graphs on one page.

The code I used is:

```
 P1=draw.pairwise.venn(20,63,6,category = c("blastp", "HMM"), lty =rep("blank",2),fill = c("#9067A7", "#9067A7"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(0,0),cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2),inverted=TRUE)
 P2=draw.pairwise.venn(3,242,3,category = c("blastp", "HMM"), lty = rep("blank",2),fill = c("#AB6857", "#AB6857"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(0,0),cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))
 P3=draw.pairwise.venn(7,107,0,category = c("blastp", "HMM"), lty = rep("blank",2),fill = c("#bc767c", "#bc767c"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(0,0),cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))
 P4=draw.pairwise.venn(11,1,0,category = c("blastp", "HMM"), lty = rep("blank",2),fill = c("#628130", "#628130"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(0,0),cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))
 grid.arrange(P1, P2, P3, P4, ncol=2)
```

But there showed an error:

```
 Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

When try:

```
 grid.arrange(grid.draw(P1), grid.draw(P2), grid.draw(P3), grid.draw(P4), ncol=2)
```

Still errors but change to :

```
only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

I want to paste these four on one page.

Answer (score 5):

I'am not sure this is related to an update, but I always arrange venndiagrams like:

```
grid.arrange(grobTree(P1), grobTree(P2), grobTree(P3), grobTree(P4), ncol=2)
```

You need to convert the venndiagrams to a grid graphical object (grob).

Comment: Suppose you can reduce the repetition with `grid.arrange(grobs=lapply(list(P1, P2, P3, P4), grobTree), ncol=2)`

Comment: @user2957945 this is much nicer!

Comment: Work excellent! Wow. Thanks both of you very much~~~~@user2957945 @ricoderks